# QT QTableWidget not appearing in QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtabwidget

I have an application which uses multiple tabs. I used `QTabWidget`. On some tabs I needed to show tables, so I used `QTableWidget`.

The code snippet is:

```
QWidget *qwgt = qPreviewTabs->widget(Index);
QTableWidget *qDrvTab = new QTableWidget();
....
....
....
QVBoxLayout *vbLyt = new QVBoxLayout();
vbLyt->addWidget(qDrvTab);
qwgt->setLayout(vbLyt);
```

When I add push buttons and tree widgets they all appear on the specified tab without any problem. Only the `QTableWidget` refuses to show.

Comment: Where are you creating the `QTableWidget`?  What is `qDrvTab`? Can you show us an example of a successful widget insertion into the tab, and the failed table widget one?

Comment: Oops sorry..qDrvTab is the table. I have edited the code snippet now. This is the failing code, in the sense the Table doesn't get shown. If i add any other widget to the Layout its showing. only Table doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

```
A table with no rows and columns is a void.
```

So do

```
qDrvTab->setRowCount(no_of_rows);
qDrvTab->setColumnCount(no_of_cols);
```

before adding it to layout.

Now you can see your Tablewidget in layout.